# Does the await call inside a while loop exit the while loop when awaiting results?

Tags: python, asynchronous, while-loop, python-asyncio

Here's the code:

```
data = []
while some_dict:
        results = await some_input_output_coroutine(some_dict)
        some_dict.clear()
        for result in results:
            data.append(result['data'])
            try:
                some_dict[result['dataId']] = result['nextPageToken']
            except:
                pass 

Code that does something with data list......
```

Basically what the 'try' does is that it checks if there is any further data, since the API just fetches 100 data items per call. If there is further data, the results would have a 'nextPageToken' and this 'nextPageToken' is used to fetch the next 100 data Items. If there is no further data items, the results dictionary will not have a 'nextPageToken'

I'm just trying to understand what happens behind the scene. Does my code exit the while loop when awaiting for results and start working with the 'Code that does something with data list'? Or does it only exit the while loop when the 'some_dict' sets to false/empty before moving on to 'Code that does something with data list'?

I intend for my code to start working with 'Code that does something with data list' as and when the results are available, instead of waiting for the while loop to be exited since that is unnecessary downtime.

Hope I made my question clear. Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: It does exit the loop and the current function, but remembers how to continue from the same place, in the same way in which a `yield` would exit the function and be able to continue later. In fact, `await` was initially implemented using `yield`.

Comment: `await` doesn’t exit anything. It blocks the current coroutines execution until whatever you await completes. Awaiting something may result in control being handed back to the event loop to allow other things to run, but that depends on the implementation of `some_input_output_coroutine`.